# How to inverse string without library functions - C++

Tags: c++, string, char

I'm having trouble with understanding how to output the inverse of the string then store the inverse value and apply it to a string variable to print the string later on. Some errors I receive depending on the structure of the program  include : random characters being printed, just the string input being printed, the programming crashing... The program must be able to process this menu:

[image]

At one point I had the inverse working, but when I would add for example if(choice == '2') and create the reverse function it would start acting up again.

This is what I have for now :

```
int main()
{
    string userString = "";
    int i = 0;
    char choice;
    char invChar = char(userString[i]);
    userString = invChar;



    cout << "Please enter a word, a sentence, or a string of numbers." << endl;
    getline(cin, userString);

    do
    {

        cout << "\nUSE THIS MENU TO MAINPULATE YOUR STRING\n"
             << "----------------------------------------" << endl;
        cout << "1) Inverse String\n" 
             << "2) Reverse String\n" 
             << "3) To Uppercase\n"
             << "4) Count Number Words\n" 
             << "5) Count Consonants\n" 
             << "6) Enter a Different String\n"
             << "7) Print the String\n" 
             << "Q) Quit" << endl;

        cin >> choice;
        cin.ignore();

        if (choice == '1')
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= userString.length(); ++i)
            {
                if (isupper(userString[i]))
                {
                    char(tolower(userString[i])); // if uppercase - converts to lower - if upper keeps value
                    invChar += userString[i];

                }

                userString = invChar;

            }       

            cout << userString;


        }

    } while (choice != 'q' || choice != 'Q');
```

Thanks in advance for any tips and tricks!

Comment: invChar += userString[i]; userString = invChar; are probably wrong lines

Comment: Why don't you just write a function to do each operation, and just call the function instead of trying to stuff the entire program in `main()`?

Comment: Also, you have a memory overwrite in that `for` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you maybe mean to do this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < userString.length(); ++i)
{
   if (isupper(userString[i]))
   {
       userString[i] = (tolower(userString[i]));
   }
   else if(islower(userString[i]))
   {
       userString[i] = (toupper(userString[i]));
   }
}
```

This will actually inverse. What you were doing before doesn't work, and also only converts to uppercase

Comment: Do you see the memory overwrite bug in that loop?  `i <= userString.length()`

Comment: @Eyal_K so how would you store the result into a string? Wouldn't we need to cast userString[i] to char first, and then store the result of that into a string in order to print later?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie you are absolutely right, I just rushed in copying code from the original sample. It's fixed now

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Hey paul, I will be writing them into functions after I figure out how to get it to work. This is an error I'm receiving regarding the loop        warning C4018: '<=' : signed/unsigned mismatch

Comment: @FranticCode userString[i] is actually a char reference already. The string that the user entered is modified here, since that is what you wanted to print. If you want, you can keep a copy of the original.

Comment: @FranticCode signed mismatch is a warning, not an error, it can be fixed by doing static_cast<int>(userString.length())

Comment: @EyalK. Thanks Eyal I will be testing this out. I'm just a beginner in c++ so I'm still stretching my brain. I really appreciate this effort.

Comment: @FranticCode I suggest you go line by line in debug mode, and make sure to keep a watch on all your variables. This will teach you a lot about how these things work, as well as show you that you did a lot of unnecessary things, like setting userstring to invchar, just before getting the userstring from the user

Comment: @EyalK. I grew so frustrated with the problem that I was trying everything I could think of that can possibly work. I greatly appreciate your help! This worked and I can finally move on to the rest of the program. One simple answer really made a huge impact. Thanks!

Comment: @FranticCode Glad I could help

Comment: "it can be fixed by doing static_cast" or not using a signed type tor `i`. for `(size_t i = 0; i < userString.length(); ++i)` Problem gone. No invoking godmode with a cast. Also can't overflow in the event of an insanely huge string.